# Are the eigenvalues always the diagonal entries of a triangular matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am a bit confused about the eigenvalues of this matrix
$$\begin{pmatrix} -4 & -1 & 1 \\ 1 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & -8 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$

MATLAB says that there is one real eigenvalue and a complex conjugate pair of eigenvalues. I tried to calculate the eigenvalues by hand by getting the matrix into upper traingular form and reading off the diagonal entries, the reduced matrix is 
$$\begin{pmatrix} -4 & -1 & 1 \\ 0 & -\frac{5}{4} & \frac{1}{4} \\ 0 & 0 & \frac{13}{5}\end{pmatrix}$$
which has only real eigenvalues.

Why is this happening? I've done a quick look around and found [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/894683/eigenvalues-of-a-matrix-using-diagonal-entries) which shows that you can't change the rows without changing the eigenvalues, which I haven't done.

What's going on? I thought that a reduced matrix has the same properties as the original matrix, so why are the eigenvalues different?

Also (this is more of a side question) how is MATLAB calculating the eigenvalues in this case? I thought this method of computing eigenvalues is the same way as MATLAB does it, but it looks like something different is going on.

Comment: Row operations do not preserve eigenvalues; think of multiplying a row of the identity matrix by a non-zero number, or swapping two rows

Comment: why don't you do the reduction on $A  -\lambda I$ and see what happens?

Comment: In general, you can't do *any* row operations without changing the eigenvalues (which includes changing rows).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $A$ be an arbitrary matrix, and suppose that it we can reduce $A$ to $R$.  Then there is an invertible matrix $M$ such that $A = MR$.

The only thing that matrices $A$ and $R$ necessarily have in common is that they have the same nullspace.  Outside of that (and any consequences), $A$ and $R$ share no notable properties.

In particular, $A$ and $R$ do **not** generally have the same eigenvalues.  If that were the case, we could argue that any invertible matrix is reducible to the identity matrix and therefore must have the eigenvalue $1$.